# How to better segmentation for the complex image?

Tags: python, image-segmentation, image-thresholding

I need to segment the testes image and detect testes tubules. But I was able to only segmented testes lumens. I need to segment the whole tubules.

How should I proceed?

Explanatory image: [image]

Comment: You can do `![description][1]` to embed the image

Comment: This is a research topic, entire groups work on such tasks at various universities, institutes. Software/packages you could check are [ilastik](https://www.ilastik.org/) and various morphological/morphometrical segmentation plug-ins for ImageJ/Fiji.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have to do it myself. This project is a thesis.